# Expected value of these random variables

Tags: probability, expectation

Say $X_0=1$ and
$$
X_n=
\begin{cases}
1-X_{n-1},&\mbox{with } p\\
X_{n-1},&\mbox{with } 1-p
\end{cases}
$$
Now, let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Is there any closed-form for $\text{E}S_n$? Like with binomial distribution we would simply have $np$.

Comment: Yes, you can write a recursive "linear difference equation" for the means $E[X_n]$, then you can solve it.

Comment: @user75619 If you consider any answer interesting, feel free to accept / upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) and the fact that $EX_i = P(X_i=1)$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
EX_i&=P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=1|X_{i-1}=0)\,P(X_{i-1}=0)+P(X_i=1|X_{i-1}=1)\,P(X_{i-1}=1)\\
&=p\,P(X_{i-1}=0)+(1-p)\,P(X_{i-1}=1)\\
&=p\,(1-P(X_{i-1}=1))+(1-p)\,P(X_{i-1}=1)\\
&=p+(1-2p)\,P(X_{i-1}=1)\\
&=p+(1-2p)\,EX_{i-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

So you have a sequence with $e_0=1$, $e_i=p+(1-2p)e_{i-1}$, which is a more or less trivial problem in Calculus.